# exporting docker container can not be performed

Tags: docker, migration, containers, export

I'm working with several docker container and needed to export one . I assumed docker export is a way to migrate container. as i am running this command as

```
docker export {container-name}
```

I'm getting this error

```
cowardly refusing to save to a terminal. Use the -o flag or redirect
```

Comment: Top hit on [google](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/) and the actual official documentation when searching for "docker export" explains how to use it. Maybe take a few seconds to try that before posting a question next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `-o` flag as it says in your error:

```
docker export {container name} -o filename
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this export file contains along with all data of that container? couldn't figure it out.